# Highcharts fill serie's color on svg marker

Tags: svg, highcharts, fill, markers

I made a drilldown bubble chart with a custom marker (instead of circles).
I used markers provided with highcharts and it's working well (see my example here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/t0oha7q6/ with square markers).
Now I'd like to use a svg image instead of square marker. It's working when I specifiy (see line 41 of the jsfiddle) :

```
marker: {
            symbol: 'url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/197729/dollar.svg)',
            lineWidth: 3,
        },
```

But my problem is that all markers are dark. I need the color of the serie values to be set on each marker (as for square or circle shape). I tried with svg without fill property but the color is never changed by Highcharts. Is that possible ?

A second question is about the bubble legend : IS it possible to get the same shape for the bubbles size legend instead of circles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that defining a symbol as an SVG element parses the SVG element into image (check in the console).

You can find information about it in the API:

> Additionally, the URL to a graphic can be given on this form: 'url(graphic.png)'. Note that for the image to be applied to exported charts, its URL needs to be accessible by the export server.
>
> Custom callbacks for symbol path generation can also be added to
> Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols. The callback is then used by
> its method name, as shown in the demo.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.symbol

And if you want to add a custom symbol you should do it via using the SVGRenderer tool, just like in the attached demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/

```
// Define a custom symbol path
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}
```